# Java-library for modeling object relations

Tags: java, relationship

I'm searching for the java library, that would allow me to draw relations between some objects(entities). What does i need from this library:

- object properties(could be groupped)
- extra information about object(could be comments or similar)
- bi-directed relations
- relations caption
- relations must be constructed between object properties

---

If my explanation is so terrible, you could look image bellow. It very similar for that i need.

[image]

Comment: You want something like a program that auto generates UML class diagrams?

Comment: I am not sure. At first(as i know), uml is not support relations based on entity properties. At second - i going to draw object-relations, that descripted not by program code, but by custom xml schema. I know about UML, but in my case its not my idea